# Alter PHP time from script without using settime

Tags: php, time

I'm thinking this is not possible, but thought I would ask. Say I have 2 functions. Function A calls Function B. Function B returns the current time. e.g

```
function a()
{
    return b();
}

function b()
{
    return time();
}
```

Say furthermore that I want to have b actually return a different time. (Say when the date is '2014-09-01') but I don't want to alter function b. (So I can't use strtotime in function b, or pass in something into function b and return that ... I'm stuck with b exactly). Is there a way to alter the time in function A so that function b returns the time specified in function a? e.g

```
function a()
{
    set_default_time_to('2014-09-01');
    return b(); // returns equivalent of strtotime('2014-09-01')
}

function b()
{
    return time();
}
```

**Edit**: I've been asked to clarify.

So I guess I overcomplicated so here's a simpler explanation without 2 functions... I want something that will do something like the following

```
function a()
{
    echo time(); // echos current time
    set_default_time_to('2014-09-01');
    echo time(); // returns equivalent of strtotime('2014-09-01')
}
```

The reason I split it into 2 functions is because I wanted to emphasise the point that I can't just alter time() to strtotime, mktime, or any other function. The second function does additional stuff, but has been removed for simplicity sake.

```
function a()
{
    echo b(); // echos current time
    set_default_time_to('2014-09-01');
    echo b(); // returns equivalent of strtotime('2014-09-01')
}

function b()
{
    $time = time();
    // Do some logic stuff here
    return $time;
}
```

I cannot alter b. It is what it is.

I also know we can use php to shell script, but I would prefer a method that does not resort to using shell scripting from php.

Comment: Just use `mktime()` instead and pass the offset seconds as argument to `b()`.

Comment: @KouberSaparev He just said he cannot change function `b` in any way

Comment: He said that he does not want to alter function b, not that he cannot. In fact, that's exactly where the inheritance OOP concept comes into play. That's the correct way to do it. Alterting the behaviour of `time()` (even if possible somehow by altering the server clock) poses much more potential troubles.

Comment: @KouberSaparev "So I can't use strototime in function b, or pass in something into function b and return that... I'm stuck with function b exactly" .... I did say I cannot alter it. It's easy to just "alter" a function... if I could do that I would just change the function and this question would be pointless... The hope is to have some php method that might be able to do this without having php resort to shell scripting and altering the server details.